# Uniqueness of Ramsey counter-examples

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I asked this question a while ago on math exchange with no satisfying answer, so I thought I'd try my luck here, if the question doesn't fit the site please close it or let me know and I'll close it.

Let $R(i,i)=k$, therefore there exists a counter example which is a coloring with blue and red edges for a clique of size $k-1$. Is it unique up to renaming the vertices? Does there exist a counter-example for $k-1$ nodes with an almost equal number of red and blue edges (any bound is welcome). Even more interesting: Is there a counter-example with a not almost equal number of red and blue edges for $k-1$ nodes? Define almost equal number however you want, I am interested in any result.

Answer (score 9):

For $i=2,3,4$ the counterexample is unique and therefore has equal numbers of edges of each colour.  For larger $i$ nobody knows the answer, though it is likely that for $i=5$ there are 656 counterexamples, only some of which have equal number of edges of each colour.

See http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/ramsey.html .

Comment: What a disappointing result :(, I secretly hoped it is unique. What about how close the number of edges must be? Any results on that?

Comment: That's an interesting question, but I don't know of any such results.